# Alchemy CMS - new module not showing in the left sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alchemy-cms

I have followed this [guide](https://guides.alchemy-cms.com/create_modules.html) to generate a new module called Users. I have updated the `icon` to be:

#### config/initializers/alchemy_user.rb

`image: 'alchemy/users_module.png'`

I have placed the image to `app/assets/images/alchemy/users_module.rb`

But the icon does not show in the left sidebar. I can navigate to `/admin/users` by typing the adres manually in the address bar.

What am I missing?

I have other modules for other models in my app, i.e. hospitals, doctors, etc. and they do appear in the left sidebar with icons.

What do I need to do in order for the new module to appear in the left sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the guys from Alchemy CMS on their Slack channel I was able to resolve this.

I had a typoo in `alchemy_user.rb` and was missing a rule in `UserAbility`.

#### alchemy_user.rb

Instead

```
Alchemy::Modules.register_module({
    controller: '/admin/user',
    ...
})
```

it should be

```
controller: '/admin/users' # plural
```

And in `user_ability.rb`

`can :manage, :admin_users`